# How to get distance <500?

Tags: php, mysql

This is my query to calculate distance using latitude longitude values .

```
SELECT mm.mem_id, mm.profilenam, mm.photo_thumb, mm.city, mm.zip, mm.country, mm.state, ( 3956 *2 * ASIN( SQRT( POWER( SIN( ( 34.1012181 - ABS( latitude ) ) * PI( ) /180 /2 ) , 2 ) + COS( 34.1012181 * PI( ) /180 ) * COS( ABS( latitude ) * PI( ) /180 ) * POWER( SIN( (
ABS( - 118.325739 ) - ABS( longitude ) ) * PI( ) /180 /2 ) , 2 ) ) )
) AS distance
FROM members AS mm
WHERE mm.profile_type =  'C'
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 0 , 10
```

i want the distance < 500 but when i put in query
... <500 AS distance , it doesn't work 
How can i get the final query.

Comment: Why do you need to take the absolute value of latitude? Looks wrong to me. Particularly since  `COS(ABS(latitude) * PI() / 180)` = `COS(latitude * PI() / 180)` for all values of latitude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried

```
SELECT mm.mem_id, mm.profilenam, mm.photo_thumb, mm.city, mm.zip, mm.country, mm.state, ( 3956 *2 * ASIN( SQRT( POWER( SIN( ( 34.1012181 - ABS( latitude ) ) * PI( ) /180 /2 ) , 2 ) + COS( 34.1012181 * PI( ) /180 ) * COS( ABS( latitude ) * PI( ) /180 ) * POWER( SIN( (
ABS( - 118.325739 ) - ABS( longitude ) ) * PI( ) /180 /2 ) , 2 ) ) )
) AS distance
FROM members AS mm
WHERE mm.profile_type =  'C'
HAVING distance<500
```

Answer (score 0):

Since that's a derived column, you need to use a HAVING clause

```
SELECT mm.mem_id, mm.profilenam, mm.photo_thumb, mm.city, mm.zip, mm.country, mm.state, ( 3956 *2 * ASIN( SQRT( POWER( SIN( (        34.1012181 - ABS( latitude ) ) * PI( ) /180 /2 ) , 2 ) + COS( 34.1012181 * PI( ) /180 ) * COS( ABS( latitude ) * PI( ) /180 ) *   POWER( SIN( (
ABS( - 118.325739 ) - ABS( longitude ) ) * PI( ) /180 /2 ) , 2 ) ) )
) AS distance
FROM members AS mm
WHERE mm.profile_type =  'C'

HAVING distance < 500

ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 0 , 10
```